# How to make default text in entry that disappears

Tags: python, tkinter, insert, default, tkinter-entry

For instance:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.insert(END, "ex. new file")  #would like to make this text disappear when clicked
e1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Where the text "ex. newfile" disappears when clicked upon, leaving a blank entry field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a boolean flag that monitors if the entry has been accessed; set it to `False`,
2. Bind "<Button-1>" to a function that clears the entry if it has not been accessed yet, and changes the flag to `True`.

Comment: Could you give an example

Comment: You can read about binding events to widgets here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm. You need to define a function that clears the Entry, whenever necessary, and bind it to the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
def delete_text(event):
  if default_text:
    e1.delete(0, END)
    default_text = False

default_text = True
e1.bind("<Button-1>", delete_text)
```

Thanks to DYZ and effbot

Comment: This will _always_ delete text. I though you wanted to delete only the original default text.

Comment: Makes sense to me, but: This gives me UnboundLocalError: local variable 'default_text' referenced before assignment, when I click on entry box and no longer deletes the text.

Comment: Oops, just move its definition before the function definition.

Comment: I tried this, but: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "zztrialszz.py", line 14, in delete_text
    if default_text:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'default_text' referenced before assignment :::: Thanks

Comment: Declare `default_text` as global in the function.